# Use https module in react native

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, react-native

I want to use the https standard library module from nodejs in react native (I need https.Agent for axios). Is there a proper way to do this?

Answer (score -1):

It can be performed with the in-build function 'fetch' of JavaScipt too.

Example :

```
fetch('https://mywebsite.com/endpoint/', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    firstParam: 'yourValue',
    secondParam: 'yourOtherValue'
  })
});
```

More : https://reactnative.dev/docs/network

Comment: How would I configure this to allow self signed certificates?

Comment: I believe it needs to implement at platform configuration.
might be helpful - https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/20488